# Can a Flex client app connect to BlazeDS running on a different server?

Tags: apache-flex, client, blazeds

As far as In understand the [Flex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flex) technology, a Flex client connects to a Flex server to retrieve business information. Is this the only allowed connection for the client, back to the originating server? Or can a Flex client also open a secondary connection to a different server wich runs [BlazeDS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flex#BlazeDS) for message exchange? (This might offer an option for load balancing and cross-platform development).

**Update**: thanks for the answer! I have found this page which links to the Cross-domain policy file specification:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**, a Flex client can connection to a variety of servers, including BlazeDS.  What could prevent a client from conenctiong to a BlazeDS server is the [crossdomain.xml](http://www.google.ch/search?aq=0&oq=crossdomain&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=crossdomain.xml), which is a connection policy document hosted on the server.

I've got one concern about your question, and that is using the term *'Flex server'*.  That was something folks talked about with Flex 1, circa 2005!  Adobe is now on Flex 4, and some relevant server technologies/platforms/software/protocols of interest are BlazeDS, [**Red5**](http://osflash.org/red5), [**FMS LiveCycle Data Services**](http://www.adobe.com/products/livecycle/dataservices/), [**JSON**](http://www.json.org/), [**AMF3**](http://www.google.ch/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=amf3), etc.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to crossdomain.xml. However, I found information at http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14213.html which says that it is not possible to connect to two servers on different domains.

Comment: @mjustin: Please re-read that link.  The subject is much more complex, there are options.  Also note that article is old--It is referencing Flash 7!  The devil is in the details, it can be done, many folks are doing it.

Comment: Thank you for your hint, see my update - accepted your answer

Answer (score 0):

If BlazeDS is your main server side endpoint and your primary goal is load balancing then you may want to explore the clustering capabilities of BlazeDS -- http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/blazeds_devguide/help.html?content=services_clustering_1.html.