# Flex dynamic change of server

Tags: php, android, web-services, apache-flex, flex4

So i am working on flex 4.6(before updating to 4.11) on a new project with php services. There is an auto-generated class called MarkerService.as which contains the following:

```
protected override function preInitializeService():void
{
    super.preInitializeService();
super._serviceControl.endpoint = "http://www.mydomain.gr/gateway.php";
}
```

However i am building a login system that changes dynamically the server in which the user will connect. So i changed the above to:

```
public var targetServer:String="test1";
protected override function preInitializeService():void
{
    super.preInitializeService();
super._serviceControl.endpoint = targetServer;

trace(targetServer+" started");
}

public function setTargetServer(s:String):void
{
    targetServer=""+s;
    super._serviceControl.endpoint = targetServer;
    trace(s+" targeted");
}
```

And then call my setter on an MXML class when the login method is called. However, it seems like the prInitializeService is called during the start of the execution and thus i get a connection error. I attach the logs from the console:

```
test1 started <--- when app is executed
test1 started <--- when login button is pressed and setter is called
http://www.mydomain.gr/gateway.php targeted
http://www.mydomain.gr/gateway.php started
Send failed
Channel.Connect.Failed error NetConnection.Call.Failed: HTTP: Failed: url: 'http:test1'
app:/test1
```

it seems like the new link is not updated after it is setted and the old test1 is used for the connection. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm curious to know why 'test1 started' appears twice. Is there > 1 instance of this class?

Comment: in order to access the setter from within the mxml, i create a new object of markersservice class

var m:services.markersservice.MarkersService=new services.markersservice.MarkersService;

when this is done, the second test1 started appears

Comment: I wonder if you are setting the 'mydomain.gr' values in one instance and doing 'channel.connect' in another.

Comment: I remember having a similar issue and also answering [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9805146/more-than-one-channel-in-blazeds/9829285#9829285). Quick solution would be to reinstantiate `_serviceControl` instead of reassigning its `endpoint` property.

Comment: flex itself generates two files for the service called _Super_MarkersService and MarkersService (markers is the name i gave to the service). The remote server, in this case mydomain.gr, is defined in the MarkerService.as which overrides the function above. Connect probably happends in mxml using <markersservice:MarkersService id="markersService"
            fault="trace(event.fault.faultString + '\n' + event.fault.faultDetail)"
            showBusyCursor="true"/>

Comment: RIAstar could you a bit more specific? You mean reinstantiate _serviceControl in the super class or in the markersservice.as one?

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise this was generated code. You shouldn't touch the generated class, so perhaps you can find where in the generated class `_serviceControl` is instantiated and override that method in your subclass. Note that this code generation is not part of the Flex SDK; it's a FlashBuilder feature (that I never use and know very little of).

Comment: well the _serviceControl is generated in _super_MarkersService and then the endpoint is changed on the MarkersService. The strange thing is that although i cahnge it on the MarkersService (override super) it seems that it already uses whatever was found when the app executed.

Could it be there is another way to change the endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after a few hours of testing and changing the logic, it seems like that the assignment of the endpoint must happen before initializing the _serviceControl. I was trying to implement my logic using states which was buggy. However, when i moved the call to the setter on a new view (loginView) everything worked like a charm. From the looks of it,  makes a direct call to the service and it is executed before the app is even displayed.

As a result, the solution for changing dynamically the server your gateway is located, is as follows:

Markers.as (or whatever you call it), changed
From

`protected override function preInitializeService():void
    {
        super.preInitializeService();
        super._serviceControl.endpoint = "http://www.mydomain.com/gateway.php";
    }`

To

```
public var targetServer:String="";
protected override function preInitializeService():void
{
    super.preInitializeService();
    super._serviceControl.endpoint = "http://www.mydomain.com/gateway.php";
}

public function setTargetServer(s:String):void
{
    targetServer=s;
    super._serviceControl.endpoint = targetServer;
    //trace(s+" targeted");
    preInitializeService();
}
```

And in your login.mxml

```
var m:services.markersservice.MarkersService=new services.markersservice.MarkersService();
            m.setTargetServer("http://www.mydomain.com/gateway.php");
            navigator.pushView(HomeView);
```

I hope this will help more Flex developers.